# Getting notes through chapter or book in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have three models:

notes, chapters and books

A note can either have a reference to a chapter (chapter_id) OR a reference to a book (book_id).  Also, a chapter has a reference to a book (book_id).

Each chapter is referencing to a client (client_id) and each client is referencing to a user (user_id)

I want to find all the distinct notes that a specific user can read.  Those are the chapter notes that belong to that user AND the book notes from those chapters.

Currently I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM notes n 
JOIN chapters c ON (c.id = n.chapter_id OR c.book_id = n.book_id)
JOIN clients cl ON (cl.id = c.client_id)
JOIN users u ON (u.id = cl.user_id)
WHERE u.id = my_user_id
```

Since I want to run this on my model because I am paginating afterwards with kaminari, I am doing it like this (using Note model):

```
Note.joins(
%(
JOIN chapters c ON (c.id = n.chapter_id OR c.book_id = n.book_id)
JOIN clients cl ON (cl.id = c.client_id)
JOIN users u ON (u.id = cl.user_id)
).
where("u.id = :id", id: given_user_id).
distinct
```

This query runs pretty slow and I have a feeling this is due to do the `OR` in the JOIN clause (I have never seen or done that before), because I have tried with two separate queries (one to fetch the chapter notes and another one to fetch the book notes) and it runs faster.

I would like to know what is a proper way to solve this problem making sure that the results are paginatable.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: If the PK of the chapter table was (book_id,chapter_id) and the FK of the note table was  the same, then a book note would simply be any note with a chapter_id of NULL.